# Subscript out of range error with active column element

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write code which looks at whether a row in the active column in ("Input Sheet") matches the contents of a cell in a range which is in a different sheet ("Sheet2").

If the contents match, the code will take the contents of the cell directly to the right of the cell in ("Sheet2") & put it into row 39 of the active column in ("Input Sheet").

I know in all likelihood this is going to have something to do with the range part of the code, but am not really getting anywhere with a solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub yellowgrey()

Dim y As Range

With y = Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(131, 1))



If Sheets("Input Sheet").Cells(38, ActiveCell.Column).Value = Sheets(“Sheet2”).Cells(y, 1) Then


Sheets("Input Sheet").Cells(39, ActiveCell.Column) = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(y, 2)


End If

End With


End Sub
```

Comment: You need to qualify every Range object, which includes `Cells()` with its appropriate parent: `Set y = Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 1), Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(131, 1))` and you need to set the object not use with, so remove the `End With`

Comment: Also you cannot use y which is Range variable as a row in Cells() as that requires a long.

Comment: (You also never `Set` y.)

Comment: I did what you said Scott, & am still getting Object required error?

Comment: Your code has many issues, and it is not quite clear as to what you want it to do, so it is hard to help.  Please post post/Mock data and expected output in the original post with edit.  You are mixing up Ranges and Longs, you are trying to compare a full range to a single cell, and the list goes on.  We need a lot more information to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was mentioned in comments, you need to *qualify* implicit references to the `ActiveSheet` and `ActiveWorkbook`. [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) (disclaimer: I'm heavily involved in the development of this [free & open-source] VBE add-in) would have identified that problem:

[image: RD code inspections results]

> Member 'Cells' implicitly references ActiveSheet

This means:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(131, 1))
```

Is really doing this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(131, 1))
```

And that's how your code breaks down whenever Sheet2 isn't the active sheet.

---

Then there's these other issues:

[image: More RD code inspection results]

I'd like to bring your attention to the **Local variable '“Sheet2”' is not declared** inspection result. Notice the double quotes are parsed as part of the identifier name - you're using curly quotes for some reason. VBA string literals must be delimited ASCII 34, i.e. `"` - anything else is not picked up as a string literal delimiter.

Variable `y` being a `Range`, its reference needs to be assigned with the `Set` keyword.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Set y = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(131, 1)    
    '...

End With
```

When you later use `y` like this:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(y, 2)
```

You're passing **the value** of the cell/range represented by `y`, because the `.Cells` call takes that `y` parameter as the `RowIndex` parameter, and since `y` is a `Range`, VBA implicitly fetches its *default property* (i.e. `Range.Value`), which makes the assignment completely dependent on what `y` contains... except `y` isn't just one cell, so it's completely unclear what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Thankyou very much Mat, your program sounds very impressive. What I am trying to achieve with y is for it to be a rowindex in ("Sheet2"), which is not something I seem to be getting right.

Comment: Thanks! It's far from perfect, but it's improving [almost] every day! As for `y`, it's still not clear how it's supposed to be a row index, since you [attempt to] assign it to `Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(131, 1))`, which spans 129 rows - if you want it to be a row index, then declare it `As Long` and assign it to a row number, not a `Range`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, with your help I have fixed it below:

```
Sub yellowgrey()

Dim hh As Long

With Sheets("Sheet2")
    For hh = 2 To 131 Step 1
        If Sheets("Input Sheet").Cells(38, ActiveCell.Column).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(hh, 1) Then
            Sheets("Input Sheet").Cells(39, ActiveCell.Column) = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(hh, 2)
        End If
    Next hh
End With

End Sub
```

the goal was to loop through the data in column 1 of (Sheet2) & see if it matched the contents of a specific cell in (Input Sheet), & perform an action if it did.

Cheers

Comment: When you use a With Block you can replace every reference with just the `.`.  So, Since you are using `With Sheets("Sheet2")` every reference to that sheet is not need inside the with block: `Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(hh, 2)` only needs to be `.Cells(hh, 2)` otherwise there is no reason for the With block.  Also, Indentation of the code at the right places makes it easier to read.

Comment: I edited your answer to indent feel free to rollback I just wanted to show you what I mean, Now you can easily see where each block starts and ends.

Comment: Don't worry, in the program I am making Activecell.column will always be in the Input Sheet when this Sub is run. Thanks for your help Mat.